# Fetching bot answers from a database

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB with MongoDB for storing the answers that my Microsoft Bot Framework-based chatbot will give to different dialogs.

**My issue is that I don't know if it's best to do a query for each response or do one large query to fetch everything in the DB once the code runs and store it in arrays.**

The [Azure Cosmos DB pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/) uses the unit Request Units per second (RU/s).

In terms of cost and speed, I'm thinking of doing one query whenever the bot service is run (in my case, that would be when `app.js` is run on my Azure Web App).

This query fetches all the data in my database and stores results in different arrays in my code. Inside my `bot.dialog()`s  I will use these arrays to fetch the answer that I wont the bot to return to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

i would load all the data from the db into the bot when the app starts up and if you manipulate the data you can write it back into the db when the bot shuts down. this would mean that you have one single big query at the beginning of your bots life and another one at the end. but this also depends on the amount of memory that your app has allocated and how big the db is

Comment: This doesn't sound like a viable pattern: it doesn't scale, and it doesn't provide data persistence (e.g. what happens when the bot exits unexpectedly, without saving any data). And doesn't sound very good for concurrency either (what happens if another bot instance is running, and cannot work with data created from the first bot instance, because it's just sitting in memory and not in the database?)

Comment: The bot will not provide any support for writing to the database. It will only read from the DB to provide answers for the different dialogs. Since it's an FAQ bot, the data amount is expected to increase from new questions, answers/facts being added to the DB.

Comment: you can load all the responses at startup for the moment and change it when you don't have the memory to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From Cosmos DB perspective fewer requests that yield larger datasets will typically be faster/cheaper in terms of RUs than more requests fetching smaller datasets. Roundtrips are expensive. But it depends on the complexity of the queries too - aggregation pipelines are more expensive than find() with filters. Everything else should be a client-side consideration